# Get reverse lookup model instances without repeating the parent model values in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Company(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField("Company Name", max_length = 200)
    started_date = models.DateField()

class Car(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField("Car Name", max_length = 200)
    display_name =  models.CharField("Brand Display Name", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank = True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cars")
```

Now if I query like this:

```
Company.objects.filter(started_date=some_date).values('id', 'name', 'cars__name')
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Ford', 'cars__name': 'Mustang'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Ford', 'cars__name': 'Shelby Mustang'}]>
```

But I do not want the values of the `Company` model repeated every time because there are multiple `Car`s associated with a `Company`.

I would like to get the values something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Ford', cars: { 'name': 'Mustang', 'name': 'Shelby Mustang'}}]>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using django filters or any aggregators. Instead you can use dictionaries like this:

```
query_list = []
for each_company in Company.objects.filter(started_date=some_date):
    result_dict = {}
    result_dict['id'] = each_company.id
    result_dict['name'] = each_company.name
    result_dict['cars'] = {'name': x.name for x in Car.objects.filter(company=each_company)}
    query_list.append(result_dict)
```

Result is a list of dictionaries:

```
query_list = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Ford', 'cars': { 'name': 'Mustang', 'name': 'Shelby Mustang'}}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Ferrari', 'cars': { 'name': '250 GTO', 'name': '125 S'}}]
```